# Sending multi-dimensional associative arrays with HTML forms

Tags: php, html, post, get, associative-array

What is best practice for sending multidimensional arrays from an HTML form using either GET or POST? I couldn't find anything from Googling..

I've done things like this (`name="array[]"`) when working with check-boxes and things, but what if I want my array to be associative/multidimensional? I wrote the following to test my theory and it works fine locally but is it reliable/best practice? Can I expect this to work when I upload to server?

```
<?php
if(count($_GET) > 0){
    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_dump($_GET);
    echo "</pre>";
}else{
    ?>
    <form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="bob dole" />
        <input type="hidden" value="myarr" name="arr[name]" />
        <input type="hidden" value="green" name="arr[color]" />
        <input type="submit" value="go" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: looks fine to me, if it does what you want then use it

Comment: Yes, it's documented behaviour, and featured on *all* PHP installations.

Comment: Thank you @mario, if you can produce a reference in an answer I will accept it. I looked for it but I could not find the documentation you speak of.

Comment: It's hidden here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays and in example 3 of http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Thakn you @mario, just what I was looking for!